# Subset dataframe in R using function inside select_if to make it conditional on a grouping variable?

Tags: r, select, dplyr, na

I would like to conditionally subset a dataframe in R, using `dplyr::select_if()`. More specifically, I have a dataframe that is made up of a grouping variable and numerous other variables that contain a bunch of `NA`s:

```
data <- tibble(group = sort(rep(letters[1:5],3)),
           var_1 = c(1,1,1,1,rep(NA,11)),
           var_2 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,rep(NA,9)),
           var_3 = 1,
           var_4 = c(1,1,rep(NA,10),1,1,1),
           var_5 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1))

# A tibble: 15 x 6
   group var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 var_5
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a         1     1     1     1     1
 2 a         1     1     1     1     1
 3 a         1     1     1    NA     1
 4 b         1     1     1    NA     1
 5 b        NA     1     1    NA     1
 6 b        NA     1     1    NA     1
 7 c        NA    NA     1    NA    NA
 8 c        NA    NA     1    NA    NA
 9 c        NA    NA     1    NA    NA
10 d        NA    NA     1    NA    NA
11 d        NA    NA     1    NA    NA
12 d        NA    NA     1    NA    NA
13 e        NA    NA     1     1     1
14 e        NA    NA     1     1     1
15 e        NA    NA     1     1     1
```

In this dataframe, I need to identify and remove columns like `var_4` in this case that only occur in one group (but irrespective of whether or not they show up in the last group: "e"). Importantly, everything else has to remain untouched (i.e. I want to keep variables that look like `var_1`,`var_2`,`var_3`, and `var_5`). This is what I tried:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  filter(group!="e") %>%         # Ignore last group.
  select_if(~ function(col)) %>% # Write function to look for cols that only have values for one group of the total four groups remaining (a-d).
  names() -> cols_to_drop        # Save col names.

data %>% select(-cols_to_drop) -> new_data # Subset by saved col names.
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to write that function inside `select_if()` to specify that grouping variable condition.

A second thing that I have been wondering about is whether I can use `select_if()` to remove cols based on the percentage of `NA`s it contains. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if `select_if` would be able to do such grouped selection of columns.

Here is one way to do this getting data in long format :

```
library(dplyr)

cols <- data %>% 
         filter(group != "e") %>%
         tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('var')) %>%
         group_by(name, group) %>%
         summarise(value = any(!is.na(value))) %>%
         summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
         filter(value > 1) %>%
         pull(name)
 
#Select the columns
data %>% select(group, cols)

#   group var_1 var_2 var_3 var_5
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a         1     1     1     1
# 2 a         1     1     1     1
# 3 a         1     1     1     1
# 4 b         1     1     1     1
# 5 b        NA     1     1     1
# 6 b        NA     1     1     1
# 7 c        NA    NA     1    NA
# 8 c        NA    NA     1    NA
# 9 c        NA    NA     1    NA
#10 d        NA    NA     1    NA
#11 d        NA    NA     1    NA
#12 d        NA    NA     1    NA
#13 e        NA    NA     1     1
#14 e        NA    NA     1     1
#15 e        NA    NA     1     1
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Though in my example it's far easier, because the variables are just called "var_", whereas in the actual dataset that's not the case. Do you know how I could adapt `pivot_longer()` to account for that. I was thinking something along the lines of `everything()` except for "group", but `everything() -group` didn't do the trick...

Comment: To provide some more detail: `pivot_longer(cols = vars(everything(), -group))` yields the following error message: `x Subscript has the wrong type `quosures`.
i It must be numeric or character.`

Comment: @FabianHabersack You can do `tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -group)`